# Emacs Gnus open two groups side by side

Tags: emacs, gnus

I'm trying to do the following. Suppose my mailbox has these groups: "inbox" and "sent mail". I want to have two buffers open in Gnus with the content of the first and the second group.

The intuitive way of opening the first group, then creating a separate buffer (via <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> for example), going back to the group list, selecting the other group and repeating the opening procedure in the new buffer does not work. Instead it removes all other buffers (including the one with the previously opened group) thus occupying the entire window and displaying the contents of the most recently opened group. When I switch to the burrowed buffer of the previously opened group it appears to be empty :/

This is not just uncomfortable, this is **super extremely** uncomfortable as most messages come in the form of send-and-respond. Not being able to read them as such is really bad...

Answer (score 0):

This irritates me too, usually when I want to find an email to refer to when I'm replying to another.

My solution is to make two frames (`M-x new-frame`). Go to the `*Group*` buffer in both and then your window configuration doesn't get messed up when you move around.

Since you mentioned that you're using Gmail in a different question, another solution for reading messages in a thread is to find one message of the thread in the "All mail" group. Then use "A T" to grab all messages in that thread, and you can read in a sort of equivalent of GMail's "conversation mode" (or whatever they call it). Then "/ T" limits to the thread, but I never end up using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're init file doesn't load too slow, it's reasonable to just open another Emacs for separate Gnus browsing.